# Codeigniter strange encryption of password

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, passwords, password-encryption

I'm new to Codeigniter and trying to make a user registration. And I've met strange thing. At first I'll tell what exactly I'm doing with my password value:

```
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
$password = md5($password);
$password = strrev($password);
```

And then I'm saving it to the DB:

```
$data = array(
    'email'     => $email,
    'reg_type'  => $reg_type,
    'password'  => $password
);

$this->CI->db->insert('user', $data);
```

And no matter what password I enter, It's always saving this value: `e7248fce8990089e402b00f89dc8d14d`

And when I'm going to login page (code of encryption is the same), it's returning me a different md5 values (and it's look like correct).

Can somebody explain why it's happens and how to solve it? Or maybe you can propose some another method of password's encryption.

Thank you.

Comment: Call it a blessing in disguise. Don't use MD5 for password storage, it's old and considered broken.

Comment: Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: sure codeigniter has something better build in?

Comment: O.T this could be usefill as a helper in CI https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Empty variable:**

*e7248fce8990089e402b00f89dc8d14d* is the reversed hash of an empty string.

This means your $password variable is empty, you probably have a bug somewhere with your `$_POST` code.

**Use Blowfish:**

As mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't use `md5()` any more.

If you have PHP 5.5+ you can use the `password_hash()` function:

`$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`

And use the codeigniter `post()` function instead of `stripslashes()` and `htmlspecialchars()`.

**Example:**

```
//Get password from form
$password = $this->input->post('field_name', true); //adding true runs the XSS filter.

//Hash Password
$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

//Data Array
$data = array(
    'email'     => $email,
    'reg_type'  => $reg_type,
    'password'  => $password
);

//Save to DB
$this->CI->db->insert('user', $data);
```

**EDIT:**

`password_hash()` handles salting on it's own. I removed the additional salting from the code. (See @martinstoeckli comment)

Comment: Using password_hash() is a good idea, but this function handles salting on its own. The salt will be part of the resulting hash-value and you do not have to handle/store it separately.