# Login is not working after updating password

Tags: codeigniter

Update password is not working

```
private function hash_password($password) 
{       
    return password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
} 



private function verify_password_hash($password, $hash)
 {
  return password_verify($password, $hash);
}
```

I have used same code to add user after adding user I can do login to the account.
But when I change the password after updating password login failed
Here is reset password code

```
public function resetPassword($id)  {
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $newdata = array(       
        'password' => $this->hash_password($password),                                            
    );
    $this->admin_model->changePassword($id,$newdata);

    $result ="Password changed";
    echo $result;
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't login because the inputted passwords hash is not equal to the passwords hash saved in the database.
Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025163/codeigniter-strange-encryption-of-password) Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi thank for the reply when I register the user password with same coding and do login it work fine for me. Only in case of change password its not working

Comment: Insert is working fine for me. after insert data I can do login.